# What is the easiest way to add an element to the end of the list?

Tags: list, ocaml

As`:: : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list` is used to add an element to the **begin** of a list, Could anyone tell me if there is a function to add an element to the **end** of a list? If not, I guess `List.rev (element::(List.rev list))` is the most straightforward way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`list@[element]` should work. `@` joins lists.

Answer (score 28):

The reason there's not a standard function to do this is that appending at the end of a list is an *anti-pattern* (aka a "snoc list" or a [Schlemiel the Painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)). Adding an element at the end of a list requires a *full copy* of the list. Adding an element at the front of the list requires allocating a single cell—the tail of the new list can just point to the old list.

That said, the most straightforward way to do it is

```
let append_item lst a = lst @ [a]
```

Answer (score 17):

Given that this operation is linear, you should not use it in the "hot" part of your code, where performance matters. In a cold part, use `list @ [element]` as suggest by `Adi`. In a hot part, rewrite your algorithm so that you don't need to do that.

The typical way to do it is to accumulate results in the *reverse* order during processing, and then reverse the whole accumulated list before returning the result. If you have N processing steps (each adding an element to the list), you therefore amortize the linear cost of reverse over N elements, so you keep a linear algorithm instead of a quadratic one.

In some case, another technique that work is to process your elements in *reverse* order, so that the accumulated results turn out to be in the right order without explicit reversal step.